# why when I enter dart in cmd (windows) does it close immediately? Same with flutterfire

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, cmd

**recently, I accidentally deleted the entire file "path" (environment variable), perhaps it lacks some variable.**
here's my flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 3.8.0-14.0.pre.8, in Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19044.2604],     localization ru-RU)
[√] Windows version (installed version of Windows - version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - development for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - development for the Internet
[!] Visual Studio - development for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.3)
X Visual Studio lacks the necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the                   "Desktop Development using C++" workload and enable these components:
MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 Build Tools
- If multiple versions of the build tool are available, install the latest one
C++ CMake Tools for Windows
Windows 10 SDK
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.75.1)
[√] Connected device (available 3)
[√] Network resources
```

it seems ok, but when I write to the console "**dart**..." or "**flutterfire**..." or just "dart" immediately closes
without error.

***[here is my **system** environment variable PATH]*(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQixu.png)

*[here is my **user** environment variable PATH]*(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZvdH.png)

i am tried to reinstall flutter sdk, but it don't helps(

Comment: Your environment is missing some defaults, and has at least one entry which should be in your User Path instead! The default entries in order should be, `%SystemRoot%\System32`, `%SystemRoot%`, `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem`, `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`, `%SystemRoot%\System32\OpenSSH`. Your Default User Path should begin with `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`, or `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps`. Please add your own locations below these, not above them, and ensure that those within a users profile tree, are added to that User's Path, not the System's.

Comment: I did as you advised, but the problem was not solved. I edited the question of the link to the photo in the post, could you look again

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also, did you see *Visual Studio lacks the necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the  "Desktop Development using C++" workload and enable these components: MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 Build Tools* in the messages?

Comment: I'm writing code in android studio. I have problems with the terminal when I write dart - it closes immediately. How can this be related to vcode?

Comment: Based upon the images you've now added as an update, **you have not followed the advice I offered**. The order of your entries is very important, I specifically gave them in the default order. You also read an **or** as an **and**, in your User Environment too!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by adding this path to the system environment variables
**`C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`**

Comment: Please, whenever you can, use environment variables in your %Path%, _(as I've already shown you)_, ```%ProgramFiles%\Git\cmd```. The locations are saved within a registry key, in the format REG_EXPAND_SZ, which is designed to efficiently expand those variable references.